# the installed ways of php

Tags: php, host

i am often see this "`the php is installed in suPHP`, that `php is installed in fastcgi`.
how do i know which way of my php is installed.thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can detect the server API in use with [php_sapi_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php).

suPHP is different from the server API. It is a security feature which enables php to run under a different user account from the webserver.